# How to reduce boilerplate of pattern matching in a list comprehension for existence of a single item

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I have a pattern like the one below that repeats a lot. Is there a way
to get rid of the boilerplate? The pattern is that I'm checking to see if
there is at least one item in `[Param]` that matches a specific constructor. If
such an item exists, I call a function with data in that value. If not,
I pass.

```
data Param = UserId Int | PostId Int | ...

...

-- in one function:

  let matches = [uid | x@(UserId uid) <- xs]
  case matches of
      [uid'] -> doSomething uid'
      _ -> return () -- do nothing

-- in another function:
  let matches = [pid | x@(PostId pid) <- xs]
  case matches of
      [pid'] -> doSomethingElse pid'
      _ -> return () -- do nothing
```

**EDIT**

I don't care if `matches` ends up being one or more elements. I just want the first element, if any.

Comment: Is there a chance that `matches` would be more than one element?  Or do you particularly care if it is?

Comment: @bheklilr Answered your question in an edit

Comment: Very slight improvement: the `x@( )` is redundant since you don't use `x`.

Comment: Thanks. That shortens things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only care about the first element, then the best choice would be to utilize `listToMaybe` in `Data.Maybe` along with the `maybe` function, you could do something like:

```
onSingleton :: Monad m => (a -> m ()) -> [a] -> m ()
onSingleton f = maybe (return ()) f . listToMaybe
```

Then you could write

```
onSingleton doSomething [uid | x@(UserId uid) <- xs]
onSingleton doSomethingElse [pid | x@(PostId pid) <- xs]
```

---

The `listToMaybe` function is very simple.  If the list passed to it is empty, it returns `Nothing`, otherwise it returns `Just (head list)`.  The `maybe` function takes a default value for when `Nothing` is passed in and a function to apply to the inside of and `Just value` passed in, so using them together means you can quickly apply a monadic function to the the first element in a list or do nothing if that list is empty.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is [`take 1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:take) and [`forM_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:forM_):

```
data Param = UserId Int | PostId Int | ...

....
  forM_ (take 1 [x | UserId x <- xs]) doSomething     
....
  forM_ (take 1 [x | PostId x <- xs]) doSomethingElse
```

Each `forM_` expression will process at most one matching element from the input.

The "actions" `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` are assumed to have types `(Monad m) => a -> m b` (or `(Monad m) => a -> m ()`, as in the question).

The type of each `forM_ ...` expression is `(Monad m) => m ()`.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular example, you don't need the list comprehension. You can patter-match everything (the list lenght, and the constructor) in the case statement :

```
case xs of
   [UserId uid] -> doSomething uid
   _ -> return ()
```

Comment: I don't think this is right. `xs` might have several elements. I want to see if it contains a (UserId uid) at any position.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that pattern-matching a list comprehension was also filtering it. I didn't answer your question but I learned something ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a` from `Data.List` which find first element in the list and you could change list comprehension

```
maybe (return ()) doSomething $ find (\x -> not $ null [0 | (UserId _) <-[x]]) xs
```

We could simplify a bit:

```
doFirst f bl xs = maybe (return ()) f $ find (not . null . bl) xs
```

And use our function

```
doFirst doSometing     (\x -> [0 | (UserId _) <-[x]]) xs
doFirst doSometingElse (\x -> [0 | (PostId _) <-[x]]) xs
```